# Create/Copy Refund on another Wordpress page (frontend)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to 'copy' the Refund process/function on frontend. My goal is to let our Store Managers to handle refunds aside from us, admins. The Store Managers have similar privileges with the admins in terms of Orders but they are not allowed to go to **wp-admin.php**.

It may be easier to just mimic the refund process (or not) but I think it's better to do it the Wordpress/Woocommerce way.

Your help is highly appreciated.[image]

Comment: Are you using WooCommerce or something else, and can you please post some code you're having trouble with.

Comment: @NathanielFlick I'm using Woocommerce. I don't have code for the refund yet, but I do have a code on other parts of the orders page on the admin side.